# run .py files in python?

Tags: scripts, python

I have a file called `ikfast_generator_cpp.py` in a directory called `openrave-0.9.0-src/python` under my home directory.

How do I run it in Python?

Comment: In a terminal, typing `python myfile.py` will run `myfile.py`.  If that doesn't help, perhaps you'd like to rephrase the question, minus the rant, and perhaps someone can be of more help.  Good luck.

Comment: @MarkSmith this is what i got when i did what you asked ubuntu@frank:~$ python ikfast_generator_cpp.py
python: can't open file 'ikfast_generator_cpp.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
sentinal@Xcorp:~$

Comment: That sounds a lot like the file isn't there.  Does it show up when you type `ls -l` ?

Comment: @MarkSmith check out this short  please Mark https://www.dropbox.com/s/dwcvsoqsjmo4qcn/ScreenCapture_11-23-2015%2011.57.43%20AM.wmv?dl=0

Comment: Are you in the directory that `ikfast_generator_cpp.py` resides in? What does `file ikfast_generator_cpp.py` say?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dwcvsoqsjmo4qcn/ScreenCapture_11-23-2015%2011.57.43%20AM.wmv?dl=0 i feel that this videos show everyone where things are and what i want to do with it, why cant i get that pointer ?

Comment: To answer your question about how to get better help - edit your question to be clearer and without the rant.  Regarding the procedure in your video, navigating to that folder in the file browser doesn't cause the terminal you open later to be in that location - it wouldn't on Windows either.  Try this: open terminal, `cd ~/openrave-0.9.0-src/python` then `python ikfast_generator_cpp.py`.  The command `ls` is a shell command (like `dir` in Windows), not a Python command.

Comment: @MarkSmith this is what i got when i input your dir link sentinal@Xcorp:~$ cd ~/openrave-0.9.0-src/python then python ikfast_generator_cpp.py
sentinal@Xcorp:~/openrave-0.9.0-src/python$

Comment: Those  are two separate commands - see my answer,  I've also edited your question to try and make it clearer - I hope it contains everything relevant.

Comment: @MarkSmith sentinal@Xcorp:~$ I type in sentinal@Xcorp:~$ cd ~/openrave-0.9.0-src/python then python ikfast_generator_cpp.py then i hit the ls and i can see the file i want to run is called ikfast.py so right after i hit ls and i see what i want i type that name here like so sentinal@Xcorp:~/openrave-0.9.0-src/python$ ikfast.py and i get this ikfast.py: command not found

Answer (score 1):

Start a terminal by clicking the appropriate icon on the left side of the screen.

In the terminal, change the current directory to the location of your file:

```
 cd ~/openrave-0.9.0-src/python
```

(The `~` means "my home directory".  I hope the rest of the line is clear.)

You should see the prompt change to include the new location.  If you like you can check by typing

```
pwd
```

Now run the Python interpreter, giving it the name of the file to run:

```
python ikfast_generator_cpp.py
```

Comment: sentinal@Xcorp:~$ 
I type in 
sentinal@Xcorp:~$ cd ~/openrave-0.9.0-src/python then python ikfast_generator_cpp.py
 then i hit the ls and i can see the file i want to run is called ikfast.py so right after i hit ls and i see what i want i type that name here like so 
sentinal@Xcorp:~/openrave-0.9.0-src/python$ ikfast.py and i get this ikfast.py: command not found

Comment: Go back through my answer, which explains what the commands do, as well as the commands to type.  You have the command there to run a Python program called `ikfast_generator_cpp.py`.  See if you can work out what you might do to run a Python program with a different name.

Answer (score 0):

To locate the file use:

```
$ locate ikfast_generator_cpp.py
```

Then when you find the path it is in, copy the path and use the following command below.

Lets say the path to your file is openrave-0.9.0-src/python/ikfast_generator_cpp.py.

To run an executable .py (Python) file, use the command:

```
$ ./openrave-0.9.0-src/python/ikfast_generator_cpp.py
```

or if it is not executable use:

```
$ python openrave-0.9.0-src/python/ikfast_generator_cpp.py
```